# Getting "Current Location" on iPhone Maps.app

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using this code to run the maps.app from my app.

```
NSString* urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", s_lat, s_long, d_lat, d_long];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

The issue is that I didn't manage to get the current location.
I want something like this:

```
 poi1.url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Current Location&daddr=%f,%f",lat,lon];
```

Comment: Why don't you try presenting a MapView inside of your app?

Comment: Because I am using a 3rd party sdk and its allow me only url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried appending the your label after the position data?

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=37.771008,+-122.41175+(You+can+insert+your+text+here)&iwloc=A&hl=en
```

Edit: And don't forget to encode your URL correctly!

```
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: It's not what i want but is the only on that is working!!(I am talking about the first one)